# Strings are not printed in accordance with the way they are allocated

Tags: c, string

In the code below my first output is coming back with my second string combined with my third.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bandNumber;
char colorOne[];
char colorTwo[];
char colorThree[];

int main(void) {
    printf("How many bands??\n");
    scanf("%d",&bandNumber);
    if(bandNumber == 3) {
        printf("\n\nEnter your first band color: ");
        scanf("%s",colorOne);
        printf("\n\nEnter your second band color: ");
        scanf("%s",colorTwo);
        printf("\n\nEnter your third band color: ");
        scanf("%s",colorThree);
        printf("\n\nBand One: %s",colorOne);
        printf("\n\nBand Two: %s",colorTwo);
        printf("\n\nBand Three: %s\n\n",colorThree);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain the errors and what I can do to correct them?

Comment: `char colorOne[];`. Are you sure your code compiles without error?

Comment: compiler shows  a warning. What's a better way to declare a string without a limit?

Comment: Code cannot "declare a string without a limit".  Code can declare a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors were not detected because either the warnings of your compiler are not enabled, being ignored or need for a better compiler.  This code does not allocate space for data being read.

Simplest solution: used fixed size arrays and limit user input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char colorOne[80+1];
    printf("How many bands??\n");
    ...
    printf("\n\nEnter your first band color: ");
    if (1 != scanf("%80s", colorOne)) Handle_EOForIOError();
    ...
    printf("\n\nBand One: %s",colorOne);
}
```

A more robust solution would use `fgets()`.  If the OS support [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), consider that.

```
int main(void) {
    char colorOne[80+1+1];
    printf("How many bands??\n");
    ...
    printf("\n\nEnter your first band color: ");
    if (fgets(colorOne, sizeof colorOne, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();

    // Delete potential ending \n
    size_t len = strlen(colorOne);
    if (len > 0 && colorOne[len-1] == '\n') colorOne[--len] = 0;
    ...
    printf("\n\nBand One: %s",colorOne);
}
```

Practice [defensive coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming)

Answer (score 1):

```
char colorOne[];
```

Array without size can be used only with this declaration like

```
char colorOne[] = "someString";
```

Else char array `colorone` cannot calculate the size of the array and store your scanned string. So this should have initializer.

Else you can have VLA(Supported from C99) like

```
int N;
scanf("%d",&N);
char colorOne[N];
```

And always there is dynamic memory allocation

```
char *colorOne = malloc(sizeof(char) * N);
```

Comment: It's a valid declaration, even if not a definition. The linker should complain about a missing symbol though.