# Why won't my program print out a character in c?

Tags: c

Why won't my program print out a character in c? I can not seem to find any error in this. Below is a snippet of my program. When I tried to print firstBand character out, all i get is nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



/*
 * 
 */

int bandOne;
int bandTwo;
double multiplierValue;
double resistanceValue;
double toleranceValue;
char firstBand;
char secondBand;
char multiplier;
char tolerance;

int main(void) {
    //prompt user for band colours
    printf("Colour of first band?\n");
    firstBand = scanf(" %c",&firstBand);
    printf("Colour of second band?\n");
    secondBand = scanf(" %c",&secondBand);
    printf("What is multiplier?\n");
    multiplier = scanf(" %c",&multiplier);
    printf("What is the tolerance?\n");
    tolerance = scanf(" %c",&tolerance);

    printf("%c\n",firstBand);

....
..
..

return 0;

}
```

please help.

Comment: Please provide a more minimal example. You're quite likely to find the answer while you create it.

Comment: `firstBand = scanf(" %c",&firstBand);`  What are you trying to do here?  Why are you assigning the return value of `scanf` to the variable being used for input to `scanf`?

Comment: @mafu what do you mean by minimal example?

Comment: Looks similar to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247798/strings-are-not-printed-in-accordance-with-the-way-they-are-allocated/28248120

Comment: I mean a program which exhibits the error, but with as few code as possible. This forces you to remove anything irrelevant

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm trying to input a character into the char variable i decleared called char firstBand. Isn't that how scan it?

Comment: Please read the documentation for scanf() `and what the return value means`:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

Comment: @XihaiLuo remove the *assignment*.

Comment: wait.. i think i see my error

Comment: Ok, Thanks guys for pointing that out. I think I can move on from here now on.

Answer (score 1):

```
firstBand = scanf(" %c",&firstBand);
```

`firstband` is a character read and scanf() returns number of elements successfully read.

So `firstBand` is no more a char which you have scanned and it is actually the value of number of elements read.

```
if(scanf(" %c",&firstBand) == 1)
printf("%c",firstBand);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all of your scanf statements from

```
firstBand = scanf(" %c",&firstBand);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&firstBand);
```

That should fix it.